# Failed to create provisioning profile for uploading app to store

Tags: ios, xcode

Ok I have created a ios app that was working fine and running in the simulator.
I am now looking to upload it to the app store.

My boss has created a developer team and add me as a admin.

When I try to create an archive (I have the scheme set to generic ios device) now I get

Failed to create provisioning profile.

Showing Recent Messages

:-1: No profiles for '****.*****' were found: Xcode couldn't find any
iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching '*****.******'. (in
target '******')

There are no devices registered in your account on the developer
website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

on the Apple developer website I have gone to

Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles and added Development certificates

What else do I need to do? Note I don't have a iphone or ipad to provision.
I was only testing in a simulator and was then going to upload to the store.

I am new to xcode. Sorry if this is simple.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually assigning provisioning profiles rather than letting XCode automatically sign your project?

You can do this by deselecting "Automatically manage signing" and
[manually selecting provisioning profiles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgQwP.png).

Also ensure that you Download the profiles you create on your Apple Developer account to XCode.

Comment: No. When I go to apple develop site and try to setup a Developer provisioning profile it eventually says there are no devices and ask me to create a device. Here it asks for a name and UUID of the device but I have no real device to register ?

Comment: Ok in the end I ignored the development profile and used a distribution profile. I was then able to compile my app and get most way through archiving.